# configuration of blazer for localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, blazer

The blazer gem [installation instructions](https://github.com/ankane/blazer#installation)  indicate

```
For production, specify your database:

ENV["BLAZER_DATABASE_URL"] = "postgres://user:password@hostname:5432/database"
```

in local development, the following error is being generated nonetheless

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

      settings["data_sources"].each do |id, s|
```

thus the data source needs to be set in `config/blazer.yml`

postgresql logs indicate

```
2024-01-14 10:14:44.406 CET [1978] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "127.0.0.1", port 5432
2024-01-14 10:14:44.407 CET [1978] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"
```

yet the following configuration

```
data_sources:
  main:
    url: "postgres://kk@example.com:12345677@127.0.0.1:5432/boilerauth_development"
```

still generates a complaint
`URI::InvalidURIError (bad URI(is not URI?):   "postgres://kk@example.com:12345677@127.0.0.1:5432/boilerauth_development"):`

where is this configuration mistaken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a special character in your username or password then you need to URI encode it. So you want to have `kk%40example.com` as your username in your connection string:

```yaml
    url: "postgres://kk%40example.com:12345677@127.0.0.1:5432/boilerauth_development"
```